# Positioning a div from one point of the screen to the far right

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have a div that begins from a certain point on the screen that needs to be in pixels and I need it to extend all the way to the right without extending the page. Can this be done somehow?

This is the CSS:

```
#fasa_right {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.60);
    top: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: 500px;
    height: 1435px;
    width: 100%;
    border-left: inset thin rgba(0,0,0,0.60);
}
```

Right now, this code makes the `div` expand all the way to the right and although I have `overflow-x: hidden` it still scrolls with middle click or side scrolling mice.

So, either something to completely disable scrolling to the right or something to make that `div` cover just enough space to fit all resolutions will do.

PS: I know I could set the whole page with percentile sized objects but there is one element in the middle of the page that needs to be set in pixels.

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/yj8rpz1q/2/ here's what happens, I clearly don't want the side scrolling to occur.

Comment: since you're using absolute positioning, have you tried clearing the width and setting right?

Answer (score 0):

By default a `div`(or any block element) will take 100% of the available width.

So, it should already extand to the right side of the screen (without adding a scrollbar) by default. If you want it to start at a certain point (not the far left), then add a `margin-left`to it.

Here's a fiddle that shows a `div` that starts 100px from the left and that goes all the way to the right : http://jsfiddle.net/yj8rpz1q/

EDIT : Does it **have** to be in `position: absolute`? I'm sorry I missed that when making the answer.

Comment: But the point is, that the div is empty, it's there for aesthetic reasons, thus without any content it gets no width, (unless I am doing something wrong) and setting the width to 100% it makes it as  wide as the whole screen thus adding a huge white block to the right of the screen that I don't want.

Comment: Even if it has no content it will take the full width, according that you define its height (look at the fiddle I linked to). However, if you set `position` to `absolute`, then you need to specify a width. Hence my edit, do you **need** the `position:absolute`

Comment: I am afraid I do need the position:absolute there is a div that takes from all the way to the left up until a fixed width div then where that fixed div ends, another -should- start ending at the far end of the screen to the right.

Answer (score 0):

keep the following settings

```
position:absolute;
top:<distance-from-top>px;
left:<distance-from-left>px;
right:0;
```